# Does the Xbox One Afterglow controller use the same conductive rubber button contacts as the regular Xbox One controller?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

My A button gets stuck sometimes (like not popping out directly after I press it). I guess the conductive rubber contact got worn out, so I want to replace it. However, I am not sure if it is the same part as in the regular Xbox One pad.

The best picture of the Afterglow contacts I could find is on Ifixit: [image: afterglow]

Does this part have a specific name? I can hardly find info about it anywhere. Would a Xbone replacement part fit?

Comment: "Rubber Domes" is how they're usually sold on speciality stores and the like. I'd imagine they would be fairly similar if not an exact match for the stock XB One controller but I can't be certain.

Comment: Thanks, rubber domes seems like an appropriate name. When searching for parts online you mostly get keyboard results, though, because it is more established there. I could not find parts for the Afterglow online, so I got one for the regular XBONE pad. It looks a little different, but I should be able to make it fit with an exacto knife. Will report the results here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got my regular XBOX One spare rubber dome and was able to repair my controller.

Here is a comparison of the old (Afterglow) and new (XBOX One) rubber domes:

[image: Old vs new]

As you can see, the XBOX button rubber dome is attached to the main rubber dome and the rubber is generally larger around the actual conducting button part. What I did not photograph are the small rims on the other side of the gray rubber dome part. The black rubber dome is completely flat on the other side.

Below you can see that the dome does not fit very well.

[image: New dome does not fit]

These are the steps I did to make it fit:

- Cut away XBOX button part (has single part in Afterglow controller)
- Noticed that select/menu button do not sit very well, so I removed that part completely. Cut the original buttons off the black rubber dome and used those.
- (Not shown) remove the small rim on the other side of the gray rubber dome that made alignment very hard.
- Removed some excess material on the top left of the gray rubber part to fit the case.

[image: With some modification it fits]

In the end, all the buttons work again. I did have to reopen the case once because the rubber dome got misaligned (the registration hole is larger than the original). The button action is not as good as it was, but way better than before with the worn out rubber dome. It took me like 30 minutes to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

> Would a Xbone replacement part fit?

Looks like the answer is no.

As you can see in this picture, this are the rubber domes for the Xbox One/One S controllers:

[image: Xbox One/One S rubber domes]

According to the picture that you sent, the "pad" doesn't have the Guide button on the same piece and the separation between the Back/Start buttons is diferent making it incompatible:

[image: Afterglow rubber domes]

Comment: You are correct, the parts are not the same. Still, I ordered one and got it to work with some modification (see my own answer).